# Global function for ExtJs 6

Tags: javascript, php, extjs, extjs6-classic

here is my Ajax function

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'report.php',
        method: 'POST',
        success: function (result, request ) {
            panel.update(result.responseText);
            mask.hide();
        }
    });
```

and my report.php look like this:

```
<tr>
<td class='center'><b>Company</b></td>
    <td class='center'><b>User</b></td>
    <td class='center'><b>Report</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php foreach ($data as $day) {?>
  if($day == $today){
<td onClick="ExtJsFunction()"><?php $today?></td>
}else{
///
}

}
```

How do i write a funciton in ExtJs code that i can call from here on click 
And i have no idea how to do it. I haven't tried anything yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do i write a funciton in ExtJs code that i can call from here on click And i have no idea how to do it. I haven't tried anything yet

I think you can use [singleton](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.Class.html) for global or common functions.

A **Singleton** is a class that can have only one object instance. In ExtJS 4 or later version a singleton object is instantiated once the application is loaded.

I have created an small [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29de) demo hope this will help you.

```
//singleton here is {singleton} class
Ext.define('Gloabal', {
    singleton: true,
    alternateClassName: 'globalUtilities',
    doApiCall: function (el) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Succes','You have clicked on <b>'+el.innerText);
        //you can call your api here...
        //on basis of your requirment
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Form',
    bodyPadding: 5,
    width: 350,

    // The form will submit an AJAX request to this URL when submitted
    url: 'save-form.php',

    // Fields will be arranged vertically, stretched to full width
    layout: 'anchor',
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%'
    },

    // The fields
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        name: 'first',
        allowBlank: false
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
        name: 'last',
        allowBlank: false
    }, {
        xtype: 'label',
        html: '<table style="width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;cursor: pointer;"><tr>' +
            '<td onclick=globalUtilities.doApiCall(this) style="border:1px solid #ccc;">API 1</td>' +
            '<td onclick=globalUtilities.doApiCall(this) style="border:1px solid #ccc;">API 2</td>' +
            '<td onclick=globalUtilities.doApiCall(this)  style="border:1px solid #ccc;">API 3</td>' +
            '</tr></table>'
    }],

    // Reset and Submit buttons
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Reset',
        handler: function () {
            this.up('form').getForm().reset();
        }
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: NO, you can also call another different way. I am referring [singleton](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.Class.html) because it will help you throughout your application. Here you can define your own required variables, methods, formats whatever you want you do here.This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system.